# add parameters to pagination

Tags: laravel, lumen

into a Laravel Lumen API project, I give back a paginated result.

```
....
"next_page_url" is "http://example.com/something?pg=2"
....
```

How can I add to all links the parameters, which are included into the requested url?

Sample:
http://example.com/something?pg=1&color=red&limit=2

next_page_url should then look like this:
    http://example.com/something?pg=2&color=red&limit=2

```
$queryStrings = Input::except('limit', 'order_by', 'order', 'page', 'count', 'current_page', 'last_page', 'next_page_url', 'per_page', 'previous_page_url', 'total', 'url', 'from', 'to', 'pg');
$limit = (Input::get('limit') ? Input::get('limit') : '10');
$order_by = (Input::get('order') ? Input::get('order') : 'id');
$order = (Input::get('order_by') ? Input::get('order_by') : 'asc');
$page = (Input::get('pg') ? Input::get('pg') : 1);

$query = DB::table('cars');

foreach ($queryStrings as $key => $value) {
    $query->where($key, '=', $value);
}

$query->select('id', 'car', 'color', 'active');
$query->orderBy($order_by, $order);

$paginated = $query->paginate($limit, ['*'], 'pg', $page);

return response()->json($paginated,200);
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `appends()` method available from the `LengthAwarePaginator` returned by the `paginate()` method. So you can simply add this line:

```php
$paginated = $query->paginate($limit, ['*'], 'pg', $page);
$paginated->appends(Input::all());

return response()->json($paginated,200);
```

This will get all input values passed and append them to the links generated by the paginator. The `appends()` method mutates the instance on which it is called, that's why you simply need to call it on the result you get from `paginate()`.

Comment: you forget links() after the appends method

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih There's no need for `links()` in this case since the pagination is serialized as a JSON response. `links()` is useful for presentation purposes to generate actuall HTML, such as when used in Blade templates.

Comment: @Bogdan you right, i thought maybe he will use the default html presentation

Comment: you can replace `Input::all()` with  `request()->input()`

Comment: @Manojkiran.A Actually you can't use the `request()` helper function, since this is a Lumen not Laravel question, and Lumen doesn't have all the helper functions that Laravel has. The `Input` and all other facades are actually disabled by default in Lumen and I'm guessing the OP enabled them manually. You can however use the service container to access the request instance by doing `app('request')` without any additional configuration in Lumen.